# Custom validation rule not activating

Tags: laravel

I have a custom validation rule that is not activating when I call it from the `Validator::make` method. My store function is like:

```
public function store(Request $request, $productor, $proveedor, $tipo, $formula)
    {
        $c1 = $request->input('1');
        $c2 = $request->input('2');
        $c3 = $request->input('3');
        $c4 = $request->input('4');

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['evaluacion' => new PasoEvaluacion($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4)]);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::action('CompletarEvaluacionController@index',[$productor, $proveedor, $tipo, $formula])->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

`c1, c2, c3, c4` are not values that will be stored in the database, only the sum of them, which will be called `evaluacion`, so `evaluacion` itself isn't an user's input.

My rule is the following

```
class PasoEvaluacion implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $ponderacion_uno;
    public $ponderacion_dos;
    public $ponderacion_tres;
    public $exito;

    public function __construct($ponderacion_uno, $ponderacion_dos, $ponderacion_tres, $exito)
    {
        $this->ponderacion_uno = $ponderacion_uno;
        $this->ponderacion_dos = $ponderacion_dos;
        $this->ponderacion_tres = $ponderacion_tres;    
        $this->exito = $exito;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        Log::info('here');
        if ($this->ponderacion_uno + $this->ponderacion_dos + $this->ponderacion_tres >= $this->exito){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Criterio reprobado';
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it seems like it's not even getting to the `new PasoEvaluacion` rule, because when I check the log it's printing nothing, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: So what happen when you reach the validation part?

Comment: @jewishmoses it shows me a blank page, it's like it completely ignores the validation part

Comment: I don't think it ignores it I think it's returning true try to add `return false;` at the start of the passes function

Comment: @jewishmoses doesn't work, still returns a blank page

Comment: @FlowMafia try `dd('passes')` after `if` statement

Comment: Solved the issue putting the sum of c1, c2, c3 and c4 in an input type hidden field and sent it through the form